# How to show data to table html from json nested loop array in php

Tags: php, html, arrays

First of all, sorry I'm newcomer with PHP and I have searched to learn what I am trying to do but could not find any solution. My question may seem simple to an expert developer. If it hurts any expert programmers ego, please do not close because any kind programmer can see and help me. Thanks.

I have json data from curl http request, that I change to array:

```
array(6) {
  ["page"]=>
  int(2)
  ["per_page"]=>
  int(6)
  ["total"]=>
  int(12)
  ["total_pages"]=>
  int(2)
  ["data"]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(7)
      ["email"]=>
      string(24) "michael.lawson@reqres.in"
      ["first_name"]=>
      string(7) "Michael"
      ["last_name"]=>
      string(6) "Lawson"
      ["avatar"]=>
      string(39) "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(8)
      ["email"]=>
      string(26) "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in"
      ["first_name"]=>
      string(7) "Lindsay"
      ["last_name"]=>
      string(8) "Ferguson"
      ["avatar"]=>
      string(39) "https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(9)
      ["email"]=>
      string(22) "tobias.funke@reqres.in"
      ["first_name"]=>
      string(6) "Tobias"
      ["last_name"]=>
      string(5) "Funke"
      ["avatar"]=>
      string(39) "https://reqres.in/img/faces/9-image.jpg"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(10)
      ["email"]=>
      string(22) "byron.fields@reqres.in"
      ["first_name"]=>
      string(5) "Byron"
      ["last_name"]=>
      string(6) "Fields"
      ["avatar"]=>
      string(40) "https://reqres.in/img/faces/10-image.jpg"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(11)
      ["email"]=>
      string(24) "george.edwards@reqres.in"
      ["first_name"]=>
      string(6) "George"
      ["last_name"]=>
      string(7) "Edwards"
      ["avatar"]=>
      string(40) "https://reqres.in/img/faces/11-image.jpg"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(12)
      ["email"]=>
      string(23) "rachel.howell@reqres.in"
      ["first_name"]=>
      string(6) "Rachel"
      ["last_name"]=>
      string(6) "Howell"
      ["avatar"]=>
      string(40) "https://reqres.in/img/faces/12-image.jpg"
    }
  }
  ["support"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(34) "https://reqres.in/#support-heading"
    ["text"]=>
    string(72) "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"
  }
}
```

I want to add this data to table in html, when I try to store the data, I cant get the true method to store the data. This is my html:

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Nama Depan</th>
                <th>Nama Belakang</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Foto</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($profile as $pro) { ?>
                <?php $no = 1; ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $no++; ?></td>
                <td><?= $profile['data'][0]['first_name'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $profile['data'][0]['last_name'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $profile['data'][0]['id'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $profile['data'][0]['avatar'] ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

How to store the data correctly from my nested array?

Comment: something like [this](https://3v4l.org/cuFnk) to get you going...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your array is saved in the `$profile` variable then your array to display is `$profile['data']`. Furthermore, using the static address [0] in the loop for this particular data structure is also wrong.
There is no additional array there. The `$pro` variable in the loop is the last array in this structure, and that's where you read specific fields.

The second thing is that in my opinion you are using the `$no` variable incorrectly. Probably every row in the table has the value 2 in this field, right? You should pass the initialization of this variable before the loop.

In my opinion, when mixing HTML with PHP, instead of curly braces, it is better to use `foreach (something):` closed by `endforeach` - it's more readable.

Try this code (I added a few comments about the `$no` variable in it)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Nama Depan</th>
            <th>Nama Belakang</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Foto</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $no = 0; /* initialization as 0 before loop */ ?>
        <?php foreach ($profile['data'] as $pro): ?>                
        <?php $no++; /* manipulating the value where it is displayed is not a good idea */ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $no ?></td>
            <td><?= $pro['first_name'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $pro['last_name'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $pro['id'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $pro['avatar'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```